# What is Boot Camp

Tags: bootcamp

I just bought a DVD of Mac OSX Snow leopard.
I am trying to install it on my PC. I can't install it and don't know why because it is first time with Mac OSX.
DVD has written on it **Boot Camp** but I thought it is Max OSX. When I read the documentation, it has written on top **How to install Windows on Mac?**.

**What is Boot Camp?**

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed by Apple's user licence to install Mac OSX on anything other than Apple hardware.... which I know doesn't answer your question, but doing that cannot be covered on these forums, sorry.

BootCamp is a 'utility' to allow Windows to be legitimately installed on Apple hardware.

Comment: He also asks how to install Mac OS X. I think we can cover that here..

Comment: Not on a 'PC' we can't.

Comment: @tetsujin is it illegal to install it on PC?

Comment: We might be pushing the definition of "illegal" [civil vs criminal] but it's certainly not sanctioned by Apple & is specifically excluded by their end user licence.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Camp is an application where you can install Windows OS onto your Mac OS X very easily. It's basically an compatible application which allows you to install Windows 7/8 on your Mac OS X hard drive partition. If you want to use BootCamp and install Windows 7/8 you can read this thread and you will know just a bit more of bootcamp and how to install windows onto it.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3986

If your a first time user with Mac OS X you might need to do a couple of things before installing Mac OS X Snow Leopard onto your hard drive. When you start up the DVD into boot options, there should be like a Utilities button and then Disk Utility up on the Menu Bar. This is what it looks like.[image]

It's very easy to install from there. When Disk Utility is open you need to follow this step to clear your hard drive and do a clean install. [image]

Then quit Disk Utility and clean install Snow Leopard, it's that easy!
[image]

Comment: FYI, OP is trying to install OS X on a PC